# variable of mixed types in R

Tags: r, csv, data-cleaning

**UPDATE**

I imported a database from CSV file using the following command:

```
data.CGS <- read.csv("filepath", sep=";", na.strings=c(""," ","NA"), stringsAsFactors =F)
```

One column in the CSV file has different types of data, numerical, integers, percentages and characters strings.

Say, for simplicity, that this column has the following elements col=[1,2,1, c, 2%, 4%, 15.5, 16.5]

So, in R will read this column as if one created this variable

```
col<-c("1","2", "c", "2%", "4%", "15.5", "16.5", "1980", "1/12/1950")
```

My purpose is to do some tabulations and compute some statistics based on the "truly" numerical data, which in this example are all values except the letter "c" **and the dates**, 1980 and 1/12/1950.

What is the easiest way to do this in R ? Any help will be much appreciated.

Of course, there is the very simple thing to do, which is to coerce all elements to be numeric, but then in R this implies convert all characters into NA - which I do not like.

Comment: Do you need the strings for further analysis?

Comment: Generally it is not correct to have different types of data in the same variable. You should spread those values into different columns of data, or convert them all to the same unit.

Comment: @RaphaelK, the short answer is, yes. The reason is that the characters/strings are responses to a questionnaire so i do not want to lose this information.

Comment: @hugo, I know, but the original database is relatively, large. How I can split this variable into another variables where in one them I can collect all numerical data and in the other the strings ?

Comment: @msh855 perhaps you should edit your question to be more precise about what you need. Is it: you want to separate different types of data into new columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to create a new vector that is separate from any text characters.

```
## Create new vector without any characters
col2 <- col[-grep("[a-zA-Z]", col)]

## To strip percentages (%)
strip_percents <- as.numeric(gsub("%", "", col2))

## All numbers except percentages
no_percents <- as.numeric(col2[-grep("%", col2)])

## Save strings in new vector
all_yo_strings <- col[grep("[a-zA-Z]", col)]

## Save percentages in a new vector
all_yo_percents <- col[grep("%", col)]
all_yo_percents <- as.numeric(gsub("%", "", all_yo_percents))/100
```

Does that work for your purposes?  It will preserve your text strings in the original `col` variable (which you can access by simply removing the `-` from `col[-grep("[a-zA-Z]", col)]`), while giving you a new, numeric vector.

Comment: Ok, this is good, as at least I have everything being numeric. But, there is a little tricky part for the numbers that are in percentages - it literally does what you suggest, i.e to remove the symbol %. The problem is that then I cannot really tell whether in the new vector the 2, comes from 2% taken out the symbol or it is the integer two. To make it short, I would prefer for example all 2% to be seeing as 0.02.

Comment: Make another vector with the percentages, then divide them by 100.

Comment: One important thing to consider, is that I then can to use cbind(), in order to put all the new vectors in the data frame. So, it seems that an extra useful step is to consider how to do this when the new vectors have different number of rows than the rows in the data frame.

Comment: That is a separate question, is it not?  Figure out how to cbind and fill in missing values with NA.

Comment: ok, great. I will. Out of curiosity I was thinking what if there were dates as well. Is there a procedure that one can extract the dates only ?

Comment: Sure, add some data with dates to your question and I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You asked a lot of questions in your question. You can have this as an example

```
 col<-data.frame(var = c("1","2", "c", "2%", "4%", "15.5", "16.5"))
col
library(dplyr)
```

by `gsub` you remove % sign from the variable `var` in `filter` you remove a `c`value from variable

```
col %>% mutate(var1 = gsub("%", "", var)) %>% filter(var1 != "c") %>% summarise(m_n = mean(as.numeric(var1)))

       m_n
1 6.833333
```

Comment: What if there are other characters besides 'c'?  We have to account for those possibilities.

Comment: It was just "c" in the example. Sure if one have more characters it is needed to acount on them